# Volley JsonArray Запрос com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException

Tags: java, json, android-volley

Есть запрос

```
{"tracks":{"track":[{"name":"Call Out My Name","duration":"0","playcount":"455465","listeners":"85596","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd/_/Call+Out+My+Name","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"The Weeknd","mbid":"c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"God's Plan","duration":"0","playcount":"1047200","listeners":"138374","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Drake/_/God%27s+Plan","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Drake","mbid":"b49b81cc-d5b7-4bdd-aadb-385df8de69a6","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Drake"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/93e7507e732722275768269b6c579a46.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/93e7507e732722275768269b6c579a46.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/93e7507e732722275768269b6c579a46.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/93e7507e732722275768269b6c579a46.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Nice For What","duration":"0","playcount":"341395","listeners":"58588","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Drake/_/Nice+For+What","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Drake","mbid":"b49b81cc-d5b7-4bdd-aadb-385df8de69a6","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Drake"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/93e7507e732722275768269b6c579a46.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/93e7507e732722275768269b6c579a46.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/93e7507e732722275768269b6c579a46.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/93e7507e732722275768269b6c579a46.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Try Me","duration":"0","playcount":"240513","listeners":"58545","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd/_/Try+Me","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"The Weeknd","mbid":"c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Wasted Times","duration":"0","playcount":"252468","listeners":"56879","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd/_/Wasted+Times","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"The Weeknd","mbid":"c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"IDGAF","duration":"0","playcount":"1221075","listeners":"137885","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Dua+Lipa/_/IDGAF","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Dua Lipa","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Dua+Lipa"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/f9cf0b274a60bc39b08f35f4d1fbcbe0.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/f9cf0b274a60bc39b08f35f4d1fbcbe0.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/f9cf0b274a60bc39b08f35f4d1fbcbe0.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/f9cf0b274a60bc39b08f35f4d1fbcbe0.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"All The Stars (with SZA)","duration":"0","playcount":"876953","listeners":"129391","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Kendrick+Lamar/_/All+The+Stars+(with+SZA)","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Kendrick Lamar","mbid":"381086ea-f511-4aba-bdf9-71c753dc5077","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Kendrick+Lamar"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/d6ca4f75a1adbfb069793b393b63a722.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/d6ca4f75a1adbfb069793b393b63a722.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/d6ca4f75a1adbfb069793b393b63a722.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/d6ca4f75a1adbfb069793b393b63a722.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Feel It Still","duration":"0","playcount":"1794427","listeners":"230700","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Portugal.+The+Man/_/Feel+It+Still","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Portugal. The Man","mbid":"3599a39e-4e10-4cb5-90d4-c8a015ebc73b","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Portugal.+The+Man"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/b86f528d1b5b232274a0ceff02c02626.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/b86f528d1b5b232274a0ceff02c02626.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/b86f528d1b5b232274a0ceff02c02626.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/b86f528d1b5b232274a0ceff02c02626.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"New Rules","duration":"0","playcount":"2848181","listeners":"218560","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Dua+Lipa/_/New+Rules","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Dua Lipa","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Dua+Lipa"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/f9cf0b274a60bc39b08f35f4d1fbcbe0.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/f9cf0b274a60bc39b08f35f4d1fbcbe0.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/f9cf0b274a60bc39b08f35f4d1fbcbe0.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/f9cf0b274a60bc39b08f35f4d1fbcbe0.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Privilege","duration":"0","playcount":"194548","listeners":"44006","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd/_/Privilege","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"The Weeknd","mbid":"c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Psycho (feat. Ty Dolla $ign)","duration":"0","playcount":"481641","listeners":"76493","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Post+Malone/_/Psycho+(feat.+Ty+Dolla+$ign)","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Post Malone","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Post+Malone"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/75c914daed6230294cb7431035e64cf5.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/75c914daed6230294cb7431035e64cf5.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/75c914daed6230294cb7431035e64cf5.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/75c914daed6230294cb7431035e64cf5.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"One Kiss (with Dua Lipa)","duration":"0","playcount":"211515","listeners":"43832","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Calvin+Harris/_/One+Kiss+(with+Dua+Lipa)","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Calvin Harris","mbid":"8dd98bdc-80ec-4e93-8509-2f46bafc09a7","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Calvin+Harris"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/ca83997a225a4368eb55f82717add274.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/ca83997a225a4368eb55f82717add274.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/ca83997a225a4368eb55f82717add274.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/ca83997a225a4368eb55f82717add274.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"FRIENDS","duration":"0","playcount":"373596","listeners":"70135","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Marshmello/_/FRIENDS","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Marshmello","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Marshmello"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/a89459d5fcd3a73f367708c194c285f4.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/a89459d5fcd3a73f367708c194c285f4.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/a89459d5fcd3a73f367708c194c285f4.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/a89459d5fcd3a73f367708c194c285f4.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"I Was Never There","duration":"0","playcount":"172495","listeners":"42213","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd/_/I+Was+Never+There","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"The Weeknd","mbid":"c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Havana","duration":"0","playcount":"3126852","listeners":"189092","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Camila+Cabello/_/Havana","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Camila Cabello","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Camila+Cabello"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/e536d25a497fd2483361a5da1b9d7321.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/e536d25a497fd2483361a5da1b9d7321.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/e536d25a497fd2483361a5da1b9d7321.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/e536d25a497fd2483361a5da1b9d7321.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"HUMBLE.","duration":"0","playcount":"2902825","listeners":"284094","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Kendrick+Lamar/_/HUMBLE.","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Kendrick Lamar","mbid":"381086ea-f511-4aba-bdf9-71c753dc5077","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Kendrick+Lamar"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/d6ca4f75a1adbfb069793b393b63a722.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/d6ca4f75a1adbfb069793b393b63a722.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/d6ca4f75a1adbfb069793b393b63a722.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/d6ca4f75a1adbfb069793b393b63a722.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Hurt You","duration":"0","playcount":"165751","listeners":"41639","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd/_/Hurt+You","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"The Weeknd","mbid":"c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/057f3cc515dac4d932378652c6b175a8.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"In My Blood","duration":"0","playcount":"442050","listeners":"45701","mbid":"","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Shawn+Mendes/_/In+My+Blood","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"Shawn Mendes","mbid":"b7d92248-97e3-4450-8057-6fe06738f735","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Shawn+Mendes"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/bc927f31d3877437bc373df46eb68aae.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/bc927f31d3877437bc373df46eb68aae.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/bc927f31d3877437bc373df46eb68aae.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/bc927f31d3877437bc373df46eb68aae.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Mr. Brightside","duration":"224","playcount":"17052390","listeners":"1902297","mbid":"37d516ab-d61f-4bcb-9316-7a0b3eb845a8","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Killers/_/Mr.+Brightside","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"The Killers","mbid":"95e1ead9-4d31-4808-a7ac-32c3614c116b","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/The+Killers"},"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/6583c8519c5393cbfdaf860f8bf6d68a.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/6583c8519c5393cbfdaf860f8bf6d68a.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/6583c8519c5393cbfdaf860f8bf6d68a.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/6583c8519c5393cbfdaf860f8bf6d68a.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"Do I Wanna Know?","duration":"272","playcount":"11223782","listeners":"826377","mbid,"@attr":{"page":"1","perPage":"50","totalPages":"1402536","total":"70126790"}}}
```

```
// Initialize a new RequestQueue instance
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

// Initialize a new JsonArrayRequest instance
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
        Request.Method.GET,
        url,
        null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // Do something with response
                //mTextView.setText(response.toString());
                Log.d("resp",response.toString());

                // Process the JSON
                try{
                    // Loop through the array elements
                    for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                        // Get current json object
                        JSONObject track = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Get the current student (json object) data
                        String t_name = track.getString("name");
                        String t_url = track.getString("url");
                        String t_dur = track.getString("duration");

                        // Display the formatted json data in text view
                        Log.d("Output", t_name + t_url + t_dur);
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                // Do something when error occurred
                Log.d("err", String.valueOf(error));

            }
        }
);

// Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Но выводить не хочет, что подскажете ?

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"tracks":{"track":[{"name":"Call Out My Name","duration":"0","playcount":"487723","listeners":"88915","mbid":"","url":"https:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/The+Weeknd\/_\/Call+Out+My+Name","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"The Weeknd","mbid":"c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9","url":"https:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/The+Weeknd"},"image":[{"#text":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/34s\/df0adcbea10fcf50f4ece63bd466abbb.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/64s\/df0adcbea10fcf50f4ece63bd466abbb.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/174s\/df0adcbea10fcf50f4ece63bd466abbb.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/df0adcbea10fcf50f4ece63bd466abbb.png","size":"extralarge"}]},{"name":"God's Plan","duration":"0","playcount":"1071873","listeners":"140612","mbid":"","url":"https:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Drake\/_\/God%27s+Plan","streamable":{"#text":"0","fullt
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас JSON битый вот в этом месте:

```
"mbid,"@attr":{"page"
```

Это примерно 674 символ в вашей строке.

Как раз об этом вам ошибка и пытается сказать:

```
org.json.JSONException
```

Полный её текст вы не привели, но суть состоит в том, что в документе нарушается структура JSON.

Не рискну пытаться её исправить. Посмотрите, что конкретно там произошло, как должно было быть — потому что это не последний дефект вашего JSON'a, ибо в конце ещё не хватает каких-то скобок, а ошибка начинается как раз примерно с этого места.

---

Если же на самом деле JSON нормальный, но при вставке в вопрос он «сломался», проблема может быть в обработке ответа сервера до его получения Volley'ем.

Либо: вы получаете `Response.Listener<JSONArray>`, однако корнем вашего ответа от сервера является объект, а не массив. Измените на JSONObject и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: полный json не влез http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=b70be2524d5997e0c0901d3480965f4e&format=json

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников с полным json'ом проблем нет, но, видимо, где-то происходит ошибка и структура ломается. Если Volley обрабатывает именно ту структуру, что вы привели в вопросе, то посмотрите, как преобразуется ответ от сервера.

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников дополнил ответ. Возможно, вместо JSONObject вы JSONArray пытаетесь использовать.